# Tanzanian passport, Canadian resident card - transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit

I am travelling with a Tanzanian passport, and a Canadian permanent resident card.  Do I need a transit visa to connect through Zurich?

Comment: From where to where to you want to fly?

Comment: As long as you don't need to collect your luggage or leave the airport, you don't need any visa for this route.

Comment: Note that for these matters in Europe, usually your residence doesn't matter as much as your citizenship

Comment: @Blackbird57 many countries offer exemptions from transit visa requirements for travelers holding visas or residence permits from other countries.  Schengen and the UK, for example, offer such an exemption for holders of US visas and "green cards."  Since residence permits show an even stronger association with the issuing country, they are even more likely to qualify the holder for a visa exemption (for example, a US residence permit with respect to travel to Canada).